# Developing app on Android TV dongle without a monitor

Tags: android

I have a question about developing app on MK808B Plus dongle. Is it possible to somehow emulate a screen in Android Studio, so I can see how my application looks, when it is running ? I know that I can buy a TV or monitor, plug my dongle via HDMI and check this out, but that's not the case.

Comment: use regular emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dongle you are using does not use the Android TV OS, but just a normal version of Android (4.4), so keep that in mind.

Yes, it is possible to emulate an android device on Android Studio. You can set up an emulator with custom settings such as screen size and os version. That way you can simulate how your application is going to look on your tv.